# Start Form in Top Right

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to start a form's position in the very top right corner of the screen. But I'd also like to do this on any screen the program runs on. So how can I go about this? Should I use the screen resolution?

Comment: It's strange because you can run your form on a specified screen only when you **set it's location** properly? Because all the screen use the same `coordinates system`, only 1 screen has `Left-Top` point at `(0,0)`

Answer (score 9):

Try using the [`Screen.AllScreens`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens.aspx) Property to iterate through all of the available `Screens` to find which one's [`Bounds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.bounds.aspx)  [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t27w02.aspx) the upper left point of your form, then setting the Forms location to A `Point` created from  `Screen.Bounds.Right` - the Forms `Width` and the `Screen.Bounds.Top` Property. Unfortunately I do not have a dual screen system available to verify it works on a screen other than the Primary, so see if something like this works for you.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    foreach (var scrn in Screen.AllScreens)
    {
        if (scrn.Bounds.Contains(this.Location))
        {
            this.Location = new Point(scrn.Bounds.Right - this.Width, scrn.Bounds.Top);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
//Get screen resolution
Rectangle res = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds; 

// Calculate location (etc. 1366 Width - form size...)
this.Location = new Point(res.Width - Size.Width);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would have the form start at the top left corner of the screen.

```
Form form1 = new Form();
form1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
form1.Location = new Point(0,0); // new Point(x position on screen, y position on screen)
```

Just remember that you specify the upper left corner of the form. So just work our the math to get it where you want it.

This would be how to get the resolution of the main screen:

```
Rectangle resolution = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
```

Or you can get the collection of all the screens using the `Screen.AllScreens` property.

Comment: I'm looking for Top Right though. How will I know where the Top Right position is on every possible screen size/resolution?

Comment: To have the right side of the form flush against the screen the x position would be (width of screen - width of form) and y would still be 0.